# Issue with angular version

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I use Angular-Meteor with Meteor list:

```
angular                         1.3.11  
angular-templates               1.0.3* 
angular:angular-animate         1.5.3_1  
angular:angular-aria            1.5.3_1  
angular:angular-material        1.0.6  
angular:angular-messages        1.5.3_1
```

I would like to use angular material last version 1.1.4 therefore I use meteor npm install and my package.json is as follow:

```
"angular": "^1.6.5",
"angular-animate": "^1.6.5",
"angular-aria": "^1.5.8",
"angular-material": "^1.1.4",
```

but when I import angualr material :

```
import ngMaterial from 'angular-material';
```

I get error on chrome  :

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function
```

as I read this error is for version of angular that not same 
My question is how I can use last version of angular-material in Meteor any help will be highly appreciate

Comment: Instead using angular as NPM dep use bower to inject the angular and run the build script that should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replay @Robust
I intall angular and angular material with bower install but when run meteor cannot build app and get error :
    `{ [Error: Package angular-material-core not found]`

    `packages/bower/plugin/handler.js:209:1: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (compiling
   bower_components/angular-material/modules/js/whiteframe/bower.json)`